# NGINX - Connecting the webSocket to the same initial http connection

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have a scenario that i'm trying to configure in nginx where I have a number of processes each listening from ports 8000,8001... Upon establishing a http connection to one of these ports I then get the client (within javascript) to establish a WebSocket connection. All the listening processes have the same /SS websocket endpoint. However if a http connection initially makes a connection to 8000 it needs to also establish the websocket connection to 8000 too. I have the following nginx configuration:

```
upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
        location / {
           proxy_pass_header Server;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
           proxy_pass http://backends;
        }

        location /SS {
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://backends;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

However this doesn't route the the websocket to the same place as the initial connection.

I thought of a way to do this where I setup different endpoints for each process and pass this through the initial http request. I would get the client to then use this endpoint for the WebSocket connection. This would however need me to configure all the different endpoints in nginx. I was wondering if there's a better way to solve this just within the nginx configuration?

Comment: It sounds like you need sticky load balancing so a given client is always sent to the same host.  See [Session persistence with NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/).

Comment: Great thanks yes that looks like what i want. Cheers